# Canonicity in split sequence in cotangent spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, sheaf-theory, locally-ringed-spaces

Let $X$ be a locally ringed space. We have for a point $p$ the exact sequence
$$0\to \mathfrak{m}_p^2\to \mathfrak{m}_p\to \mathfrak{m}_p/\mathfrak{m}_p^2 \to 0$$
where $\mathfrak{m}_p$ is the maximal ideal of the stalk $\mathcal{O}_{X,p}$. ¿Is it possible to make this sequence split in a "canonical" way under some possible additional hypothesis?

The intuition behind this is the following. An element of $\mathfrak{m}_p$ is a pair $(U,f)$ with $U$ an open neighbourhood of $p$ and $f\in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$, so a splitting of this sequence could be reinterpreted as extending a cotangent vector to a function on a neighbourhood of $p$ in a (hopefully canonical) way. In case that the answer to the first question is negative, ¿taking as a criteria making this "extension" the nicest possible can we do it in a canonical way? I hope this is not too vague.

An example could be to consider $\mathbb{R}$ and extend $f+\mathfrak{m}_p^2\in T_p^*\mathbb{R}$ to $t\mapsto f'(p)t$.

Comment: Even in the more restrictive category of smooth manifolds, there is no 'canonical' way to do this, if by 'canonical' one means 'invariant under diffeomorphims'.  However, in the category of smooth $n$-manifolds endowed with an affine connection, there is such a *local* 'splitting' defined by the connection, based on the fact that such a connection defines, for each $p\in M$ a diffeomorphism from a neighborhood of $0_p$ in $T_pM$ to a neighborhood of $p\in M$, so that one can use the 'linearity' of the vector space $T_pM$ to define the local splitting by Taylor series based at $0_p$.

Comment: Thank you for your example! It seems that those local splittings, if compatible, would also give the affine connection and splittings of this kind would be additional structure on a locally ringed space.